# VBA to copy sheets from all files in folder and copy it to master

Tags: vba, excel

I have a folder full of multiple excel files and all of the files have a specific sheet that i need to copy into my master.

I need macro to open all files in that folder one by one and copy the specific sheet to the master file using the source file name as sheet name in the master workbook. Excel 2013.

I tried searching online and have the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim wkbDest As Workbook
Dim wksDest As Worksheet
Dim wkbSource As Workbook
Dim wksSource As Worksheet
Dim MyPath As String
Dim MyFile As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wkbDest = ThisWorkbook
Set wksDest = wkbDest.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'change the destination sheet name accordingly

MyPath = "H:\Cutover\"

If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\"

MyFile = Dir(MyPath & "*.xls")

Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
    Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFile)
    Set wksSource = wkbSource.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'change the source sheet name accordingly
    'Your copy/paste code here (((((need help here please))))))))
    wkbSource.Close savechanges:=False
    MyFile = Dir
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Completed...", vbInformation

End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

So i manage to get to the below however its still not working properly. It doesn't rename the sheet to the source filename. Can someone please help?

Option Explicit

Sub test()

```
Dim wkbDest As Workbook
Dim wksDest As Worksheet
Dim wkbSource As Workbook
Dim wksSource As Worksheet
Dim MyPath As String
Dim MyFile As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wkbDest = ThisWorkbook
Set wksDest = wkbDest.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'change the destination sheet name accordingly

MyPath = "H:\Cutover\"

If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\"

MyFile = Dir(MyPath & "*.xlsx")

Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
    Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFile)
    Set wksSource = wkbSource.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'change the source sheet name accordingly
    Sheets("SheetToCopy").Copy Before:=Workbooks("WorkbookToPasteIn").Sheets(SheetIndex)
    wkbSource.Close savechanges:=False
    MyFile = Dir
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Completed...", vbInformation
```

End Sub

Comment: @dominic111 can you help please?

Comment: @a.s.h Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

so the part you need help with is how to copy/paste a range from a worksheet in one file to a common worksheet in a destination file?

set up a variable to track the last empty row in the destination sheet

look up how to determine what the last row is in each source sheet, select that source range, copy it into the clipboard, and then paste it at the last empty row in the destination sheet, and reset the destination variable to the new first blank row in the destination sheet

---

an alternative way of doing it would be to open an output CSV file, and parse each row and build up a string and write it to the file without closing the output CSV file until the loop is over

---

if the files are large tho, it would be much better to use VB.NET instead as it is much faster at dealing with large files

---

you could also read each file/row into an in-memory datatable and then output the datatable to a CSV file, or to the destination Excel file

which method would you prefer?

Comment: the files are not big . max of 300 rows with only one sheet in them. All i need is to copy the whole sheet and paste it in the master workbook as a sheet with the source filename as sheet name. Sorry very new to VBA

Comment: @A.S.H can you help?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply copy your sheet in the new workbook, following this code:

`Sheets("SheetToCopy").Copy Before:=Workbooks("WorkbookToPasteIn").Sheets(SheetIndex)`

And then, rename the sheet to fit your means.

Comment: thanks fo rthis. It works however it fails after 2 workbooks saying" this name is already taken" . i need to use the file name as the sheetname .

Comment: Then immediately change the name after pasting. If you have twice the same sheet name, it will obviously not work.